# Make this fibonacci stream stop before it overflows

Tags: scala, fibonacci

The [Scala docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_14.html) present this Fibonacci definition using Streams

```
def fibFrom(a: Int, b: Int): Stream[Int] = a #:: fibFrom(b, a + b)
```

Unfortunately, this overflows `Int` around the 47th number

```
scala> fibFrom(1,1).take(47).toList
res5: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 3, /* snip */, 1836311903, -1323752223)
```

How would I change `fibsFrom` to *end* when `a.toLong + b.toLong > Int.MaxValue` such that:

```
scala> fibsFrom(1,1).take(9999999).toList
res6: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 3, /* snip */, 1836311903)
```

I tried the following, but it behaves identically to the original `fibFrom`

```
def fibFromSafe(a: Int, b: Int): Stream[Int] = {
  if(a.toLong + b.toLong > Int.MaxValue) Stream.cons(a, Stream.cons(b, Stream.empty))
  else Stream.cons(a, fibFromSafe(b, a + b))
}
```

Comment: I've deleted an answer that suggested `fibFrom(1,1).takeWhile(_ > 0).toList` -- realised that you want to end the stream *instead* of returning a value that would overflow.

Comment: @RichardClose `fibFrom(1,1).takeWhile(_ > 0)` should work, and will return a `Stream` that ends when it should, unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Yeah, I just felt that checking for overflow by going negative was a bit gauche, and also I should have provided a function that worked as required.

Comment: I wonder why you need such a sequence. I would just use BigInt

Comment: @HappyCoder I'm merely using the Fibonacci example as a method of learning how streams work. What I really wanted to learn here is how to create a Stream that ends. The actual sequence is meaningless outside of verifying that my code is working as expected.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner I agree with Richard that that solution feels gauche. Strictly speaking, checking if a number is negative is a poor test for integer overflow, although in this specific case I think it would work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, `fibFromSafe` calls your original `fibFrom`.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the original definition of `fibFrom`. If b is negative the function stops searching for more numbers and returns an empty stream.

```
  def fibFromSafe(a: Int = 1, b: Int = 1): Stream[Int] = {
    a #:: (if (b > 0) fibFromSafe(b, a + b) else Stream.empty)
  }

  fibFromSafe().take(100).toList
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want to check for overflows you can stop when a > 3/5 of Int.MaxInt.

```
def fibFromSafe(a: Int = 1, b: Int = 1): Stream[Int] = {
  a #:: (if (a < Int.MaxValue/5*3) fibFromSafe(b, a + b) else Stream.empty)
}
```

Comment: I voted this up because the solution is much cleaner to me, but I still prefer checking for overflow rather than negativity so I accepted the other answer.

Comment: An alternative if you don't want to use `.toLong` neither check for overflow is to stop when a > 3/5 of Int.MaxInt. 3/5 is an approximation of the division of two consecutive elements: `a #:: (if (a < Int.MaxValue/5*3) ...`